# TypeError: AWS.Chime is not a constructor vuejs

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, vue.js

ResizeObserverEntry.ts:12 Uncaught TypeError: AWS.Chime is not a constructor

```
My vuejs is:
  const uuid require('uuid/v4');
    const AWS require('aws-sdk');
    const chime new AWS.Chime({region:'us-east-1'})
```

Comment: const uuid = require('uuid/v4');
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    const chime = new AWS.Chime({region:'us-east-1'});

Comment: ResizeObserverEntry.ts:12 Uncaught TypeError: AWS.Chime is not a constructor
    at Module../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./resources/js/components/ExampleComponent.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (ResizeObserverEntry.ts:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (ResizeObserverEntry.ts:12)